# Multiple Vector Paths In Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector

I am trying to use Photoshop CS5 to make a vector image of a garbage can. The garbage can will contain a few distinct parts that will be different colors and overlapping: A Lid, a can, and dark grooves on the can.

What is the best (or one good) way to model this in Photoshop? I have been using the Pen tool to make a bunch of Paths on a layer, but once I color in the paths with a color, then tweak the locations of the paths, I have to recolor them in and it is a disaster. I want to move already made selections and have the colors move with it. Is shapes what I want here? Sorry, I am a newb :)

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you have to recolor based on location?

Comment: @Johannes Let's say I have a rectangle path and I color it gray, but then I want to make the retangle into a trapezoid, so I move the path. The color does not move with the resizing of the path, but I want the new trapezoid to be gray as well.

Comment: Change your pen setting from "path" to "shape" that should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Examples:

Path: Notice how the path and color are disconnected.

[image: Path]

Shape:
Notice how the color fills to the path given.

[image: shape]